# Is there a character that will take up the full height of a line on a terminal?

Tags: unix, unicode, terminal

I'm making a command line version of the board game [Blokus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blokus) and I'd like to have the pieces take up the full height of a line. I tried to use the Unicode character █ (U+2588) but it leaves vertical gaps in the lines like so:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can have it take up the full line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The U+2588 should take full height of a line in a terminal, but due to font issues, it does not always do that.

The Block Elements characters are described in clause 15.8 [*Geometrical symbols*](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch15.pdf#page=30) in the Unicode character: “the legacy block elements are designed to fill some defined fraction of each display cell or to fill each display cell with some defined degree of shading. […] When emulating terminal applications, fonts that implement the block element characters should be designed so that adjacent
glyphs for characters such as U+2588 full block create solid patterns with no gaps between them.”

However, [fonts that support U+2588](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2588/fontsupport.htm) do not always implement it correctly. So you should check whether you can set the font to one that has a correct glyph for U+2588, such as DejaVu Sans.

If you are using U+2588 and friends in an environment that is more complicated than a simple terminal, such as software emulating a simple terminal, or in a word processor, you probably have another issue, too. Even though U+2588, when implemented correctly in a font, takes the full height of the *font*, it does not usually take the full height of the *line*. Normally line height is larger than font height (font size), and you would need to take extra measures to make them the same (to make the text “set solid”).

Comment: Yep, the line height was not equal to the font height. Problem solved.

Answer (score 13):

Those characters are, by definition, supposed to fill the entire character cell. If they aren't, there may be an issue with the font you're using. (For instance, your default font may not have that character, so the terminal is having to use a substitute font with different metrics.)

You may be able to work around this by "faking" a block character by entering inverse video mode (`"\x1b[7m"`) and outputting a space character, then switching back (`"\x1b[0m"`) when you're done.